# Вытащить значения из таблици в базе данных

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

У меня есть таблица в базе данных, где хранятся вопросы. Функция mysqli_fetch_assoc() выводит все значения, а мне нужно, чтобы выводило определенное. Пример: 3 вопроса 1) Как дела 2) Как зовут 3) Сколько лет. Мне нужно, чтобы вывело не все 3 вопроса, а например на первой странице вопрос №2, на второй странице вопрос №1 и т.д. Не понимаю, как мне вытащить определенный элемент из таблицы. Помогите пожалуйста)))

'''

```
<?php
    $db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "test");
    $result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM questions");
    if ($result){
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            echo $row['question'];
            
        }
                
    }
?>
```

'''

Comment: Ну если у записей в базе данных есть ID то обращаться к ней, в зависимости от того какая запись нужна с условием, вообще сложно что-то советовать не видя структуру вашей таблицы бд

Comment: Вариантов много, зависит от логики. Пока что не очень понятна суть, но видимо вам или нужно указывать в WHERE конкретные ID вопроса, или ограничивать выборку через LIMIT/OFFSET

Answer (score 0):

Видимо вопрос по SQL для начинающих. Как известно, чтобы выбрать те данные из БД, что нам нужны необходимо описать условие фильтрации этих данных, т.е "дай мне записи, в которых вопрос равен 'Сколько лет'".
Предположим, что в вашей таблице `questions` существует колонка `question`, в которой и находятся эти текстовые вопросы. Тогда SQL будет следующим:

```
mysqli_query($db, 'SELECT * FROM questions WHERE question = "Сколько лет"')
```

Простые примеры различного вида запросов можно посмотреть тут
https://www.w3schools.com/mysql/mysql_select.asp